# Unable to generate objects for both @higherkind and @extension

Tags: gradle, kotlin, kapt, arrow-kt

I define two objects:

1. `data class ParserK` annotated with `@higherkind`
2. `interface ParserKFunctor` annotated with `@extension`

Here is the code:

```
@higherkind
data class ParserK<A>(val f: (String) -> Option<A>): ParserKOf<A> {
    companion object
}

@extension
interface ParserKFunctor : Functor<ForParserK> {
    override fun <A, B> Kind<ForParserK, A>.map(f: (A) -> B): Kind<ForParserK, B> {
        ...
    }
}
```

When I execute `./gradlew :app:kaptKotlin` I get:

```
error: "Arrow's annotations can only be used on Kotlin classes". Not valid for error.NonExistentClass

> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsKotlin

> Task :app:kaptKotlin FAILED
e: error: Arrow's annotations can only be used on Kotlin classes. Not valid for error.NonExistentClass                                           

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

Here is what I discovered:

1. If I remove the functor definition then the goal completes successfully and I can see the generated code.
2. If I remove `@higherkind` from the data class `ParserK` and copy the generated sources into the same file where `ParserK` is defined then I can see the generated code for the functor.

It seems like a bug for me, correct me if I am wrong, please

**UPDATED:**

1. Here is the link to the repository with my code: [repository](https://github.com/neshkeev/kotlin-arrow-demo)
2. The issue on the bug tracker is [here](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow/issues/1417)

Comment: I've got the exact same problem. Have you filed an issue with arrow-kt?

Comment: @AleksandarDimitrov, we have found the solution for the issue, feel free to check the repository for references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(For arrow-version 0.9.1-SNAPSHOT and prior)

The Higherkinded Processor and Extension Processors have a dependency. Correctly, the extension annotation depends on the code generated by the higherkinded annotation. Why check this [link](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/patterns/glossary/#using-higher-kinds-with-typeclasses).

The brief summary is, whenever you try implementing typeclasses the compiler needs the Higherkinded Types of your datatype.

```
@extension
interface ListKFunctor : Functor<ForListK> {
//                                ^^^^^^^^
//                    This exists after building your module
  override fun <A, B> Kind<ForListK, A>.map(f: (A) -> B): Kind<ForListK, B> {
    return this.fix().map(f)
  }
}
```

**The simplest answer to this question is:**

`Always separate your Higherkinded Types from your typeclass definitions.`

But Arrow is experimenting with other options on Codegen. Meaning in future releases this problem will be solved.